# List all the scheduled snapshots in a given project and region programmatically (golang)

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use a golang client to programmatically list all the scheduled snapshot policies in a given project and region and describe them.

I am able to fetch them using gcloud commands, but wondering how I can do the same programmatically (preferably compute golang client)?

```
gcloud  compute resource-policies list  --project myproject
gcloud  compute resource-policies describe my-snapshot-policy  --project myproject --region myregion
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We will help you with code **you** write. Read the documentation on the Go SDK, write code, and then post a question.

Answer (score 1):

Per @john-hanley, you are encouraged to demonstrate your own attempt to solve the problem in your question.

Google provides SDKs for all of its services. There are 2 flavors and this can be confusing. The original style which you can find for any Google service are called API Client Libraries. For Google Cloud Platform many (!) of the services also (!) have Cloud Client Libraries. See Google [Client Libraries Explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

For Compute for Golang, there's a new [Cloud Client Library](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1).

You can see examples of its use [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#client-libraries-install-go). I encourage you to follow Google's style including by using Application Default Credentials.

You will want to use a [`ResourcePoliciesClient`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1#ResourcePoliciesClient) and the client's [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1#ResourcePoliciesClient.Get) and [`List`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1#ResourcePoliciesClient.List) methods.